# GET live event recording return raw data instead of link Microsoft Grap API

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I want to get the recording of the live event that i created using graph api but the issue is it returns raw data of the video instead of a link as stated in the documentation.
I also have consented all permissions required.

Here is a link to the relevant documentation :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

The following include the code and its output.
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBKDA.png)

## The code is as follow:

```
$recording=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/onlineMeetings/{LIVEid}/recording" -Method 'GET' -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers $Header
```

## Sample of the output Data

```
 *ðã    A¢h@ ¼àÀ'    @ @ @ @ Rù@}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óé®(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢'
 @ @ @ @ 
 Rù@}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óé®(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢
 AR¯n0
                                                                                                     An&«À
                                                                                                          A7       *ðã
                                                                                                                      A¢hH ¼àÀ'    @ @ @ @
 Rù@}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óé®(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢
 AT¯n0
                                                                                                                   An&«À
                                                                                                                        A7       @*ðã
     A¢hP ¼àÀ'    @ @ @ @ Rù@}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óé®(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢'
 @ @ @ @ 
 Rù@}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óéôú}>Óé®(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢(¢
 AV¯n0
                                                                                                     An&«À
                                                                                                          A7      `*ðã
                                                                                                                      A¢hX
```

#### Question

Any Ideas for the reason that it is not getting the link or how to fix that? Or if there is a way to convert this data back to a video!

Comment: [Edit] the question and include your code and link to the relevant documentation too.

Comment: @vonPryz
 I included the link to the documentation and the image. you can view the image by clicking on the image tag. i do not know how to make it appear in the question.

Comment: There are [multiple reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/503046) why images of code and/or errors are to be avoided.

Comment: @vonPryz thank you very much for your clarifications, but my case is that I have a new account and I can't add images due to that. I added a sample of the output as text instead of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code sample and the example, what happens here is that `Invoke-RestMethod` will get a HTTP 302 Found URI redirection answer, which is followed by the location of the video.

Since `Invoke-RestMethod` follows redirection five times [per default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.2), it follows the redirection link and downloads the video.

To get only the link, try passing `-MaximunRedirection 0` switch to the cmdlet to disable automatic redirection handling.

Comment: thank you for your response but I tired it now, it did not work. the same output. This situation also applies for the attendee report, it should return a link to an excel file but it return (data separated by commas)